# 'something here' matching query does not exist

Tags: django, heroku

I created a web app and deployed on Heroku successfully even database migrations. When I open the app I see the error like this:

```
'something here' matching query does not exist.
```

App URL: https://lp7.herokuapp.com/lp7/

App isn't working and if I remove this data feild from model, then app works but no single data is coming from database. But, when I go to heroku database it shows:

```
No. of Tables = 28
No. Rows = 220
Size of data = 9.4Mb
```

It means, the all migrations exists on heroku but not showing on website.

Any solution..?

Comment: the error is not about migration, its about not having any data on that table. did you populate the table for Topbar in heroku?

Comment: It works fine on localhost. I have have changed nothing in code.

Comment: If I remove this table and then none of the data populated even again from other models and the site worked statically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the table for model `Topbar` in Heroku. You can use admin-site to update it.

Also, for future, you might want to change from:

```
num = TopBar.objects.get()
```

to

```
num = TopBar.objects.last()
```

So it will return the [**`last object created in queryset`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#last). It will return None if no object has been created for `TopBar`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the traceback https://lp7.herokuapp.com/lp7/ it is bad here

`num = TopBar.objects.get()` you should pass something matching

if you dont need it do it like

```
try:
    num = TopBar.objects.get(id=1)
except TopBar.DoesNotExist:
    pass
    #handle if not found logic here
```

Answer (score 0):

For migrating data from your local database to heroku database is to run:

1. `python manage.py dumpdata yourapp > yourapp/fixtures/app_data.json`

Then you need to commit this file to heroku branch, for example:

2. `git commit heroku main`

After commiting run the following command to load data into heroku database:

3. `heroku run python manage.py loaddata app_data`